# Find percentage based on multiple column criteria in R

Tags: r, sum, match, sumifs

I've a dataframe with the following values:

```
visitDate   espEvent    sum(count)
1/2/05       s_All       1352
1/2/05      s_Animal      6
1/2/05        s_CD        4
1/4/05       s_All      1412
1/4/05       s_Animal     4
1/4/05        s_CD        2
```

I would like to find the percent of values espEvent for each Visit Date by keeping the espEvent 's_All' at 100%

The resulting dataframe should look as below:

```
visitDate   espEvent    sum(count)  Percent
1/2/05       s_All       1352        100%
1/2/05      s_Animal      6          0.44%
1/2/05        s_CD        4          0.29%
1/4/05       s_All      1412         100%
1/4/05       s_Animal     4          0.97%
1/4/05        s_CD        2          0.48%
```

Thank you for the help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Edit:* From @thelatemail's comment, changing the `.SD` to `sum` which should improve speed. A `data.table` solution would be:

```
dt[,percent := sum*100/sum[espEvent=="s_All"], by = (visitDate)]
dt

#  visitDate espEvent  sum     percent
#1:    1/2/05    s_All 1352 100.0000000
#2:    1/2/05 s_Animal    6   0.4437870
#3:    1/2/05     s_CD    4   0.2958580
#4:    1/4/05    s_All 1412 100.0000000
#5:    1/4/05 s_Animal    4   0.2832861
#6:    1/4/05     s_CD    2   0.1416431
```

This will always compute the percent relative to the row where `espEvent == "s_All"`.

**Data:**

```
dt <- structure(list(visitDate = c("1/2/05", "1/2/05", "1/2/05", "1/4/05", 
                "1/4/05", "1/4/05"), espEvent = c("s_All", "s_Animal", "s_CD", 
                "s_All", "s_Animal", "s_CD"), sum = c(1352L, 6L, 4L, 1412L, 4L, 
                2L)), .Names = c("visitDate", "espEvent", "sum"), row.names = c(NA, 
                -6L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

*Edit:* Speed test - since I was curious I decided to time using the `sum` and my original `.SD` - looks like `sum` is much faster:

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(sum = dt[,percent := sum*100/sum[espEvent=="s_All"], by = (visitDate)],
               .SD = dt[,percent := sum*100/.SD[espEvent=="s_All", sum], by = (visitDate)])

#Unit: microseconds
# expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
#  sum  814.043  934.400 1035.136  984.082 1105.372 1670.071   100
#  .SD 1630.884 1846.173 1987.738 1977.260 2093.886 2496.242   100
```

Comment: There's no need to use `.SD` - `dat[,percent := sum*100/sum[espEvent=="s_All"], by=visitDate]` will do it. In a large dataset this will make a huge relative difference in speed.

Answer (score 3):

Here's hot to do that in `dplyr`. This supposes that `s_All` will always be the maximum each day.

```
df1<-read.table(text="visitDate  espEvent    count
1/2/05       s_All       1352
1/2/05      s_Animal      6
1/2/05        s_CD        4
1/4/05       s_All      1412
1/4/05       s_Animal     4
1/4/05        s_CD        2",header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
group_by(visitDate) %>%
mutate(Percent=count/max(count)*100)

  visitDate espEvent count     Percent
      <chr>    <chr> <int>       <dbl>
1    1/2/05    s_All  1352 100.0000000
2    1/2/05 s_Animal     6   0.4437870
3    1/2/05     s_CD     4   0.2958580
4    1/4/05    s_All  1412 100.0000000
5    1/4/05 s_Animal     4   0.2832861
6    1/4/05     s_CD     2   0.1416431
```

**EDIT** A solution that does not rely on `max`.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
group_by(visitDate) %>% 
mutate(percent = count*100/count[espEvent == "s_All"])

  visitDate espEvent count.x count.y     Percent
      <chr>    <chr>   <int>   <int>       <dbl>
1    1/2/05    s_All    1352    1352 100.0000000
2    1/2/05 s_Animal       6    1352   0.4437870
3    1/2/05     s_CD       4    1352   0.2958580
4    1/4/05    s_All    1412    1412 100.0000000
5    1/4/05 s_Animal       4    1412   0.2832861
6    1/4/05     s_CD       2    1412   0.1416431
```

Comment: Hi,
Thanks a lot ! This is exactly what I had been looking for !

Btw is there a way to do this by ignoring the fact that s_All will be max all the time ?
Thanks again

Comment: It can be made exactly in the same manner as @Mike H. solution with `data.table`: `df1 %>% group_by(visitDate) %>% mutate(percent = count*100/count[espEvent == "s_All"])`

Comment: @GregoryDemin Neat! Thank you.